# How to get an image from drawables via onclick on a button

Tags: android, button, canvas, onclicklistener

How can I get a button which can get an image from the drawables folder via an onclick listener programatically not using xml. I have created a button and a shape on canvas but cannot get the button to be onclick...any idea?

Answer (score 1):

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        imageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.image);       
    }
});
```

I think this helps.

Comment: i think thats right but it shows imageview has an error how do i initialise imageview, as my view is the canvas so all is based on java, no xml

Comment: is it that you want to dynamically create an imageview?

Comment: i dont want to create an image view as i have an ordinary button but want to add the piece of code which allows me to pull an image from the drawables...sorry but do you have team viewer? i can show you my screen if you dont mind

Comment: i dont know how to...can u not have a look at it via team viewer...please help me out on this...need it completed today

Comment: did you get the solution, if not give me your mail id i have done a test project of popupwindow dynamically i will send you that.

Comment: Hi there mate... i didnt get no attached docs I think you forgot to attach the file

Comment: The file u sent me is a .rar file, I dont have a convertor can you send me the code in another file like notepad ?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to set a function which be triggered whenever the user clicks the button. You make that in the properties of your button within the layout xml file:

```
android:onClick="someFunction"
```

You'll need to create this function inside of the Activity to which the view is being bound:

```
public void someFunction(View v){
    // Load the drawable
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
LinearLayout mLinearLayout;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Create a LinearLayout in which to add the ImageView
    mLinearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);

    // Instantiate an ImageView and define its properties
    ImageView i = new ImageView(this);
    i.setImageResource(R.drawable.my_image);
    i.setAdjustViewBounds(true); // set the ImageView bounds to match the Drawable's dimensions
    i.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    // Add the ImageView to the layout and set the layout as the content view
    mLinearLayout.addView(i);
    setContentView(mLinearLayout);
}
```

You can read more about using `Canvas` and `Drawables` [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html).

Answer (score 0):

Why don't u use an ImageButton and set the background as the image taken from drawables?
Something like that

```
ImageButton imgBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(....)
imgBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.your_resource_id)
imgBtn.setOnclickListener(.......)
```

Hope this help you.

Comment: 'button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 // Perform action on click
             }
         });'                                                                                                                                                                                               So this is the code which I want to add a onclick which can get an image from the drawables folder so it will be something R.drawable.image something like that but I dont remember how it goes and cannot find much support online.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried it and (suppose) a button of ID `click` will load a drawable to an ImageView. Make sure the ImageView has not declared the src attribute.

`android:src="@drawable/something "`  must not be there.

Here is how you load the drawable programmatically.

```
    ImageView img;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    img=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgViewone);

    Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.click);
    button.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.te7);


        }


    });

}
```